# xamarin checkbox inside listview visibility change

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have xamarin.forms app which contains a List view. I implemented a long press gesture for view cell of list view. Which works fine.What I am trying to do is, inside my list view there is a checkbox and its visibility property is set bind to data model. Defaultly it will be false. If I long pressed the view cell I want all checkbox to be visible.My purpose is multi select the list view.How can I accomplish that?

**My data model**

```
 public class TimeSheetListData
        {       
            public string StartDate { get; set; }
            public string EndDate { get; set; }
            public bool Selected { get; set; }
            public bool IsCheckBoxVisible { get; set; }
        }
```

I am simply setting the API data to the item source of listview.

```
ObservableCollection<TimeSheetListData> resultObjForApprovedTimeSheetList = new ObservableCollection<TimeSheetListData>();
```

After API call,

```
 TimesheetListView.ItemsSource = resultObjForApprovedTimeSheetList;
```

**My Longpress Event and changing the chekbox visiblility.**

```
   private void CustomView_LongPressEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {                                
            foreach (TimeSheetListData TS in resultObjForApprovedTimeSheetList)
            {

                TSData.IsCheckBoxVisible = true;
            }
                TimesheetListView.ItemsSource = null;
                TimesheetListView.ItemsSource = resultObjForApprovedTimeSheetList
            }
```

It will change the visiblity of checkbox to true. But it will only visible when listview scrolled.
How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface so that we could update the UI in runtime.

#### model

```
public class TimeSheetListData: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public string StartDate { get; set; }
    public string EndDate { get; set; }

    private bool selected;
    public bool Selected {

        get 
        {
            return selected;
        }

        set
        {
            if (value!= null)
            {
                selected = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Selected");
            }
        }
    }

    private bool isCheckBoxVisible;
    public bool IsCheckBoxVisible
    {

        get
        {
            return isCheckBoxVisible;
        }

        set
        {
            if (value != null)
            {
                isCheckBoxVisible = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("IsCheckBoxVisible");
            }
        }
    }

   
}
```

Comment: Can we implement it in backend code? I am not using mvvm

Comment: You just need to add the above code to `TimeSheetListData`.

Comment: Ok bro..Let me check

Comment: You are awesome bro..It worked. Can you give me another help? When I hold press on view cell, how to make the checkbox selected for that single cell?

Comment: You could accept it firstly and create a new thread with more details about  the issue .So that people can help you better .

Comment: You could provide a sample so that people could help you to improve it .